# Order by Datetime - Report Builder 3.0

Tags: reportbuilder3.0

I'm new here (I guess you already noticed x3...). I'm the engineer Diana De La Torre, I'm actually "on training" in Fresnillo PLC company so they wanted me to develop a Project based in the the SQL server reporting services (SSRS). They want me to make reports of some processes in this company with Report Builder 3.0. I've learned a lot about it but I just have a trouble when I try to order the report results by "BitacoraTime" (That is a datetime field). 
It just won't work at all. I've tried to change the sentence and to order this report by month and/or day and It won't work either.

I've tried a lot of things and looked everywhere here on the internet.

I "tested" the same Query in the SQL Server Management Studio and all the sentences I tried to put an order to the results are working well, so it makes me think the trouble in here is the Report Builder 3.0 itself.

I really need a hand in here, I don't have enough experience to figure this out myself when everything I tried didn't work at all and I'm a Little bit desperate.

I would really appreciate if someone in here just give me a clue or something.
Thank you so much for taking the time of Reading this. :3

-Diana De La Torre.
(Ps: Sorry if my english is bad heh. I'm still improving it x3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I could solve this problem.
I really thought you could order a Tablix by a Query or by clicking the right button on it and selecting how do you want to order the results but nothing of this worked.

But suddenly I found out that clicking the right button on the exact field you want to order by you could find an option called "Dynamic Sorting" and you just have to configure that option so when you run the Report you can click on that field so it orders the results Ascendant or Descendant.

This is not exactly what I wanted because I wanted the results to be in order by just running the report model but Oh well, it won't work anyway.

I hope this can help some other people who present this problem.